# How do I set window.location to a specific path (without a host)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the window location method to redirect a webpage to another after a set amount of time.

The url needs to change from www.myurl.com/home to www.myurl.com/other. The problem is that I do not know what the final URLs will be so I cannot use absolute links, they have to be a path only. This is what I have so far:

```
 window.location.pathname = "mobility.html"
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can just prepend a `/` to your URL to make them relative to the domain root (without having to hardcode the domain name). Like this:

```
window.location = "/mobility.html"
```

Comment: That's slightly better but if my url is: www.myurl.com/folder/folder/home it changes it to www.myurl.com/other. Which does not work.

Comment: This solutions allows you to not hardcode the domain name, but you have to hardcode whatever comes after that. Maybe I didn't understand your question correctly?

Comment: I was hoping it would allow me to redirect to an html file within the same directory. Thanks

Comment: Then your original code should work! Did you try removing `.pathname`, like in `window.location= "mobility.html"`?

Comment: I removed pathname and the forward slash and it works perfectly. Ta

Answer (score 5):

`window.location.assign("/path")` also works.