# What is the difference in "/urlString.html" versus "urlString.html" in window.location?

Tags: javascript, window.location

I recently ran into an issue when preparing a web app to work in IE11. I've found a working solution but I would prefer to have a good reason why it worked rather than a guess.

My issue was an incorrect path when redirecting from the URL (http: //localhost:4724/View/Completion) to an exit page using the following javascript:

```
window.location = "Exit.aspx?timeout=true";
```

This resulted in a URL like so in IE11. Note the extra /View/:

> http: //localhost:4724/View/Exit.aspx?timeout=true

In Chrome it results in the correct URL of:

> http: //localhost:4724/Exit.aspx?timeout=true

I was able to correct the issue by including a forward slash when using window.location like so:

```
window.location = "/Exit.aspx?timeout=true";
```

Then it correctly routes Chrome and IE11 to the URL of:

> http ://localhost:4724/Exit.aspx?timeout=true

What is IE11 interpreting differently when I include the forward slash for the window.location string?

Comment: I think IE11 is actually behaving correctly here. Without the / the url is relative to the current directory which in this case is /view similar to what you would do with images etc. for css, not sure why Chrome would work as you expect

Comment: Yeah I find it really strange that chrome ever worked with this logic now that I better understand the URL relative/absolute logic. Now I guess I'll investigate why this ever worked in the first place. (I'm not (totally) crazy I can still get chrome to work without the leading slash via the console).

Comment: Ok, not sure this will ever help anyone but the issue was around the usage of a relative base tag. Chrome seems to handle it ok while IE11 expects an absolute base tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A leading slash indicates an absolute path, i.e. a path relative to the root of the website. Without the leading slash the path is relative to the *current* URL.

Why it behaves differently in different browsers I can not say.

Comment: This was my suspicion, but the inconsistency between browsers threw me off.

Comment: If you assign to `location.pathname` instead, this shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10109360/js-window-location-relative-url) - Use `window.location` for an absolute path, `window.location.pathname` for relative.