# ie11 window.location relative paths

Tags: javascript, html

I have a bit of javascript...

```
function genURL() {
        var searchSubmit = document.getElementById("search").value;
        if(searchSubmit == ""){
            window.location = "webpage/view";
        }
        else{
            window.location = "webpage/view/generate/" + searchSubmit;
        }
```

So this seems to work fine in chrome and Mozilla, however I tested in IE11 and it decided to change the pathing on me. So the redirect looks like this on Mozilla and Chrome...

```
www.mywebsite.com/webpage/view/generate
```

However on IE11 is decides to go...

```
www.mywebsite.com/webpage/webpage/view/generate
```

The page I am running it from is...

```
www.mywebsite.com/webpage/view
```

Any ways around this?

Cheers

Comment: `window.location` must work differently in the browsers. Try absolute path with leading forward slash: `window.location = "/webpage/view";`

Comment: @Papa Hey, This won't work for us since we are currently are using a location header for our url using nginx. This basically means that our web servers url always has /{insert word here} appended to it.. so www.mywebsite.com/{insert word here}. I would like a fix that covers the 3 browsers I mentioned.

Comment: Have you tried using `window.location.href`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference in "/urlString.html" versus "urlString.html" in window.location?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22666166/what-is-the-difference-in-urlstring-html-versus-urlstring-html-in-window-lo)

Answer (score 0):

Use the html `<base>` element to tell the application root.

Say, in your `<head>`, specify the application root:

```
<base id="myBase" href="//mydomain/myapp" />
```

Then in your Javascript,

```
var baseUrl = document.getElementById("myBase").href;
window.location = baseUrl + "webpage/view";
```