# Netsuite - Dynamically determine domain url

Tags: portlet, netsuite

I have been researching for quite a while now about how to dynamically determine the domain url of a netsuite account.

In general I have seen developers hardcoding domain url to "https://system.na1.netsuite.com" or "https://system.netsuite.com" in portlets.

But nobody determines it dynamically.

This in general is a bad practice(although I know Netsuite redirects) and I presume there should be way to determine the correct URL.

Can anyone help in this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what you're trying to find the URL for, you can use `nlapiResolveURL` to dynamically generate the URL for several different NetSuite objects (Suitelets, records, etc). I suggest investigating that function to see if it fits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Another options is to check the current environment.
You can use nlobjContext to get the environment. Below is the code snippet

```
var url = 'sandboxurl';
if(nlapiGetContext().getEnvironment()=='PRODUCTION'){
    url = 'productionurl';
}
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your needs, you may simply be better using relative urls. If you use window.location, anything that starts with a / is a relative location: [How do I set window.location to a specific path (without a host)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10109360/js-window-location-relative-url) has a good example.

If there is a specific example of what you are using the url for, we might be able to help more!